# How to read website content in Flutter webview?

Tags: flutter, webview

I want to read the contents of a page opened with Flutter webview. Before the page opens, the user needs to manually enter the information on the previous page, and I have no chance to do this in the background with http. How can I get the data on the opened page with WebView (which can be webview_flutter or flutter_webview_plugin). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing out of the box exactly for that purpose, however, `webview_flutter` supports communicating with the page using `JavascriptChannel`. Using `controller.evaluateJavascript`, you can inject a script that sends the page content to the channel using [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). See the examples in the [plugin repo](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/webview_flutter/example/lib/main.dart).